# Creating a list from formated multiple lines output of a file

Tags: python

I am trying to work on a TEXT file where I am reading a file and trying to create a list from multiple lines.

```
with open(filename1, 'r') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            strings2 = []
            strings1 = line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1]
            print ("Text 1 output is: {}".format(strings1))
            strings2 = strings1.split(',')
    print ("output-1 is:{}".format(strings3))
```

File.TXT:

```
12345: apple is fruit
34354: grapes is also fruit
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
[apple is fruit, grapes is also fruit]
```

Actual OUTPUT:

```
[grapes is also fruit]
```

Comment: Are there line breaks in your input text file?

Comment: yes, just updated my sample file as above

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename1, 'r') as file1:
    lines = [' '.join(line.split(" ")[1:]).rstrip() for line in file1]
```

Assuming you can gurantee the file format, that would be fine. This assumes that anything preceeding the first space is unused. If you want to split it by the colon (i.e. `1234:testing 123` without a space), then you can do something like:

```
with open(filename1, 'r') as file1:
    lines = [':'.join(line.split(":")[1:]).strip() for line in file1]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help you out

```
>>> with open(filename) as f:
...  lst = [line.rstrip('\n').split(': ')[1] for line in f]
... 
>>> lst
['apple is fruit', 'grapes is also fruit']
```

Comment: In case my answer solves your question better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move the `strings2` initialization outside your for-loop and use append? For instance:

```
with open(filename1, 'r') as file1:
    strings2 = []
    for line in file1:
        strings1 = line.rsplit(': ', 1)[1].strip()
        print "Text 1 output is: {}".format(strings1)
        strings2.append(strings1)

print strings2
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the output with \n added into each element

Comment: Okay, you can use `.strip()` to get rid of that.. see updated answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!